# Subtract diagonal terms from the matrix to make it negative semi-definite

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading [one paper](http://stat.berkeley.edu/~pradeepr/paperz/thesis.pdf) and on page 36 (48 in the pdf) it says:

> > Let d(s, i) be the (positive) diagonal terms that need to be subtracted from the matrix to make it negative semi-definite...

Could someone explain me why it's possible and how can I get the values of these terms?

Comment: I think you need to tell us more about the matrix and the context. Is the matrix Hermitian and positive definite to start?

Comment: The paper is master thesis on Markov Random Fields and matrix elements are potentials of the variables.

here is the thesis: http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~pradeepr/paperz/thesis.pdf

Comment: My quote was from page 36 (48 in the pdf).

Comment: This might just be my lack of expertise in this area talking, but this seems like a question much better suited for direct email with the author.

Answer (score 5):

If $M$ is a Hermitian matrix, its eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ are all real.  If you subtract $d$ from all the diagonal elements, you are changing $M$ to $M - d I$; if $d \ge \max_j \lambda_j$, all eigenvalues of $M - d I$ will be nonpositive so $M - d I$ will be negative semidefinite.

Comment: That's nice, but what would be in more general case?

Comment: Ok, let M be symmetrical matrix

Comment: More general in what way? Perhaps subtracting $d_i$ from $M_{i,i}$ for each $i$?  Then if $\min_i d_i \ge \max_j \lambda_j$, the new
matrix will be negative semidefinite.